# How to timestamp derivative posts or comments to a post?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase

Im working on a tutorial and thought it would be nice to timestamp comments as well.

What I have is that timestamp for posts works but not for the post's derivatives or child, or for simplicity sake, we can call them comments.

As Im using Firebase, Im not sure how to put that in Firebase so attached in Plunkr is a simplified version. If you know Firebase, feel free to write a version that hooks up with Firebase.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/QKGMIZWVwjHPrPXATY3U?p=preview
```

Appreciate your advice folks! Thanks!

**Misc infor**

For normal parent posts, this is what I did.

**In plunkr**

```
add : function (post){
      this.posts.push({id: this.posts.length, url: post.url, title: post.title, created: new Date().toUTCString()});
```

**In actual app**

```
 $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: '', timestamp: new Date().toUTCString()};
```

**html is largely same for both plunkr and actual...**

```
 creation time: {{post.created}}
```

So how should I timestamp the child posts?
Apart from the changes I inserted...see postview.js line 26 to 36 and tab-showpost.html for lines 9 to 23.

Answer (score 0):

The holy grail is Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP. You can read up on it right here and see examples:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/servervalue/timestamp.html